# How to open a new window for each item clicked?

Tags: python, window, pyqt

I select several files using getOpenFileNames and put them in a QListWidget. I also managed to have a window opened by double clicking on an item with the filename for title. However, if I click on another item it closes the previous window.

How can I open a window for each item that I click on without closing the others?

The purpose is to perform mathematical operations on each datafile in the QListWidget and I would like to visualize each dataset at the same time on the screen, and then save the data modified.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from dataGet.GetVar import Get
from datapath import *
import sys

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, item, parent = None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        horiz = 600
        vert  = 600
        self.setGeometry(self.width()/2, self.height()/2,horiz,vert)    
        self.setWindowTitle(item)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):  
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)

        self._setupActions()
        self._setupList()
        self._setupUi()

    def _addFiles(self):
        files = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self,"Open File", dirpath,"txt Files    (*.txt)")

        self.stringlist = []
        for string in files:
            self.stringlist.append(string)       

        self.flightlist.addItems(self.stringlist)

        self.flightlist.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self._openwidgets)

    def _getData(self):
        #get variables from file
        self._addFiles
        var = Get(self._addFiles,'Ozo').Var()   

    def _openwidgets(self):

        item = self.flightlist.currentItem().text()        
        self.plotwidget = Widget(item)
        self.plotwidget.show()

    def _setupActions(self):
        self.exitAct = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(':/images/exit.png'),"E&xit", self,     shortcut="Ctrl+Q",
        statusTip="Exit", triggered=self.close)  

        self.addFilesAct = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(':/images/open.png'),"Add &Files", self, shortcut=QtGui.QKeySequence.Open,
        statusTip="add files", triggered=self._addFiles)     

    def _setupList(self):
        #Build the flightlist selection
        self.flightlist = QtGui.QListWidget(self)

    def _setupUi(self):
        # Window size
        horiz = 500
        vert  = 500
        self.setGeometry(self.width()/2, self.height()/2,horiz,vert)
        self.setWindowTitle("try-1.0")

        #MenuBar
        self.FileMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&File")
        self.FileMenu.addAction(self.addFilesAct)
        self.FileMenu.addSeparator();
        self.FileMenu.addAction(self.exitAct)

        #FileList
        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.flightlist)  

        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

In `_openwidgets(self)` you are asigning the object of newly created widget to `self.plotwidget`, when you create another widget, it's object is stored in the same variable and the previously created one loses it's reference and hence the window is closed by the system.  (The window will remain opened as long as at least one variable contains it's object)

If you want all the windows to be opened, try saving their objects in a `list` as follows:

```
window = Widget(self.flightlist.currentItem().text())
window.show()
self.plotwidgets.append(window)
```

Note: Don't forget to declare `self.plotwidgets` inside your `__init__()` as a `list`